# Issues in using custom keyboard in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have downloaded a sample project from [this](https://github.com/gregheo/clicky) link for using custom keyboard.

It works perfectly.

But, when I used that in my project it returns an error - `-[UIView playKeyboardClick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71d6390`

What had I done -

I added new viewcontoller files `NerdKeyboard.h` and `NerdKeyboard.m` and `UIView` files for `NerdKeyboardView.h` and `NerdKeyboardView.m`. and I pasted the same coding from the sample project and do the same design in xib.

But when I click the button in the NerdKeyboard.xib file it returns an error

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView playKeyboardClick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71d6390'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1d1d4bd 0x1c81bbc 0x1c8194e 0x2769 0x10e3705 0x172c0 0x17258 0xd8021 0xd857f 0xd76e8 0x46cef 0x46f02 0x24d4a 0x16698 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1bec7e3 0x1bec668 0x13ffc 0x1ebd 0x1de5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`

If you want to see the Code:

**NerdKeyboard.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NerdKeyboard : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;

- (IBAction)keyPress:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender;

@end
```

**NerdKeyboard.m**

```
#import "NerdKeyboard.h"
#import "NerdKeyboardView.h"

@implementation NerdKeyboard

- (IBAction)keyPress:(id)sender
{
   [(NerdKeyboardView *)self.view playKeyboardClick];

   if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(setText:)]) {
       NSString *oldText = [self.delegate text];
       NSString *thisKey = [[(UIButton *)sender titleLabel] text];

       [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:[oldText stringByAppendingString:thisKey]];
   } else if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(nerdKeyPress:)]) {
       [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(nerdKeyPress:) withObject:[[(UIButton *)sender titleLabel] text]];
   }
}

- (IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender
{
   if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder)]) {
       [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];
   }
}

@end
```

**NerdKeyboardView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NerdKeyboardView : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>

- (void)playKeyboardClick;

@end
```

**NerdKeyboardView.m**

```
#import "NerdKeyboardView.h"

@implementation NerdKeyboardView

- (BOOL)enableInputClicksWhenVisible {
    return YES;
}

- (void)playKeyboardClick
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
}

@end
```

when I debug it the error is thrown in the line `[(NerdKeyboardView *)self.view playKeyboardClick];`

what may be the issue?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your view controller's view is a plain `UIView` and not a `NerdKeyboardView`. Make sure that you set the class correctly in the xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error comes if the connection is not correct or the OS is not able to find the function defined.If you are using xib,check if the connections are more correctly.otherwise check if the function **setText** is written correctly.maybe there can be an issue with the casing or the name of the function.

Comment: connections has no problem, when I debug it the error is thrown in the  lie `[(NerdKeyboardView *)self.view playKeyboardClick];`

Comment: put a breakpoint in the playkeyboardclick method and debug to see if the control is going inside it..otherwise there is some issue with the self.view..maybe it is nil

Comment: I've solved the issue, @omz's comment helped me to lift out the issue, keep stack_overflowing friend